# Hide a div then fade in another div when user scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I need to have a div fade out when scrolled and fade in another on the same line.

The page is 100% height, and at the bottom it has instructions to scroll. I need those instructions to fade out and new instructions fade in when the user scrolls to the section below the 100% height intro section.

Is there a simple way to do this with jquery?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/pLf9b

I need the scroll to view to be visible first, then show the Book one and two text as soon as user scrolls the section

Found this but doesnt work to what i am after

```
 var divs = $('.social, .title');
 $(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() <10 ){
     divs.stop(true,true).fadeIn("fast");
 } else {
     divs.stop(true,true).fadeOut("fast");
 }
 });​
```

Comment: Have you tried anything for this :)

Comment: Yeah tried a few things i found, but nothing similar to what im after

They seem to only activate once the page is fully scrolled to the bottom

Comment: Please include a fiddle on what you have tried already

Comment: Sorry, was taking awhile to get it together. Tho jqueyr isnt working on this

http://jsfiddle.net/pLf9b/

I need the scroll to view to be visible first, then show the Book one and two text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#column-left').scroll(function() {..}
```

and

```
 $('#column-right').scroll(function() {..}
```

instead of

```
$(window).scroll
```

and the `fadein()` and `fadeout()` functions will work fine.

And you will need some more minor modification to achieve what you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, Im hopeless when it comes to writing jquery.

Comment: Thats my fiddle, wasnt changed.

Comment: Thank you, that does work, however i need the Book text to start off hidden and then show once the scroll text disappears. Is that possible @Sharun

Comment: The text that sits on either side of Scroll to view more. 
i want 
<div class="column-name left">BOOK ONE &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; LIFESTYLE &amp; INTERIORS</div> and the one on the otherside to display none on load, the when the scroll is trigger and the scroll text disappears, i want the two divs to show like how the scroll to view disappears, does that make sense?

Comment: i think i did it off your code, http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/5esBK/1/. Is this the best possible way..
Its a bit buggy, flashes sometimes, not smooth

Comment: thank you very much, that last fiddle is exactly what i was after.